# Delete rows that have been cloned

Tags: c#, datagridview

I clone datagridview2 to datagridview3. And now i need to delete those rows that have been cloned.

```
 var duplicateTable = (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).Clone();
```

and then

```
duplicateTable.Rows.Add(row2.Row.ItemArray);
```

Comment: duplicateTable.Clear()? Is this what you need?

Comment: if i do duplicateTable.clear() it will clear datagridview3.

Comment: Then I think you dont need Clone. Try Copy instead. i.e. var duplicateTable = (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).Copy();

Comment: it will copy same info more then once. and there is still info in datagridview2.

Comment: No, what i meant was use copy method to copy datatable into another datatable and then use clear method to remove all the rows from the new table.